# $.post jquery result fill more than one field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I use this jquery `$.post` to find some data in a form. Here my code

```
$.post('action.php', {name: name}, function(data){('#element_one').val(data)};
```

and this is ma action.php

```
if(isset( $_POST['name'])===true && empty($_POST['name'])===false){

$query=mysql_query("SELECT money as money FROM customer WHERE name='".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['name']))."'");
echo (mysql_num_rows($query)!==0)? mysql_result($query, 0, 'name') : 'name not found';}
```

It work's perfectly if I must find the value of an input field (in this case the field with id="element_one").

Suppose now that I want to retrive more data from action.php and I'd like to fill more input field. How can archieve this?

In action php I can lunch a while but how changes the jquery code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a `json` object instead of single value in your php code and fetch it in the success function like following :

**PHP code :**

```
print_r( json_encode(array("val1", "val2")) );
```

**JS code :**

```
$.post('page.php', {name: name}, function(data){
     var data = JSON.parse(data);

     $('#element_one').val(data[0]); //data[0] return "val1"
     $('#element_two').val(data[1]); //data[1] return val2"
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry, testing your code it appears some errors..using chrome developper tool it show me that data value is = "
↵Array↵(↵ [0] => NAME↵ [1] => PRENAME, but doesn't fill the field...

Comment: @cicciopasticcio check my updated answer, it should work 100%.

Comment: thanks a lot Zakaria, it was mine error!Great worker:-)!

Answer (score 0):

You could return a string with `|` separated String with different values.
Then, after success, you could split that string in different string objects like

```
responseText.split("|")[0];
responseText.split("|")[1];
```

and then you can use these values in the query.

Another way is to return your response in JSON form in key value pair .

Comment: Returning JSON would be a much better option.